# Show that $\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(x-1)(y-1)(x+y-1)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\frac{2\pi}{105}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, expected-value, closed-form

How can we show that $\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(x-1)(y-1)(x+y-1)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\frac{2\pi}{105}$ ?

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hjayty7hnp?lang=zh-CN) says it's true.

The inner indefinite integral is [not nice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B%5C%2840%29x-1%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29y-1%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29x%2By-1%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D). And strangely, when I plug in the inner limits of integration $x=1$ and $x=1-y$, I get $0-0=0$, contradicting the Desmos result. (**Edit:** I should cancel factors in numerator and denominator, then I don't get $0-0$. But then I get $\int_0^1 -\frac14 y^2\sqrt{y-1}\sinh^{-1}(i) \mathrm dy$ and I don't know how to continue.)

Based on [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4812190/398708) of mine about a double integral, I tried substituting $a=x-1$ and $b=y-1$, which leads to $\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1-b}^0\sqrt{ab(a+b+1)}\mathrm da\mathrm db$, which has [another inner indefinite integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5Bab%5C%2840%29a%2Bb%2B1%5C%2841%29%5D%2Ca%5D) that is not nice.

**Context:** I asked myself, "A unit stick is broken at two uniformly random points; given that the three pieces form a triangle (which has [probability $\frac14$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2014/494920)), what is the expected area of the triangle? The answer is $\frac12$ times the integral in this question (which is supported by experimental trials, and also this [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24340565?seq=1)). This question was inspired by another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4839681/398708) about breaking a stick at random points.

Comment: I suspect that you will receive a more positive response from MathSE reviewers if you show all of your work, directly in your posting, in a very clear, well organized manner.  If you tried more than one approach, please include the additional approaches.  Further, assuming that the problem was assigned from a book/class, there must have been previously worked examples, theorems, or solved problems, that led up to this problem.  I also suggest that you regard these as your tools, and include a summary of any tools that might be pertinent, directly in your posting.

Comment: $a=x-1$ is a good substitution here so it's unclear why you had no success afterwards. What did you obtain? As a hint to finish the integral, try to think of a substitution that isolates both variables (after $a=x-1$) - e.g. to obtain something like $\int \int f(x) g(y) dxdy$

Comment: @Zacky I have editted, showing my result after substitution. Thanks for the hint; I'm not sure what further substitution would isolate both variables.

Comment: I don't get $ 0 $ when I plug in either $ x = 1 $ or $ x = 1 - y $ to the indefinite integral that you got from Wolfram Alpha.  If I plug these directly into Wolfram's expression, I got $ 0 / 0 $, and if I cancel the factors first (which Wolfram refuses to do automatically, probably because of it defaults to complex numbers), then I get $ 0 $ for neither of them (and I get different results so their difference isn't $ 0 $ either).  So while this may not be the best way to approach it, you don't get $ 0 $.

Comment: @Dan Aah I got it now, thanks for sharing. You did the two substitutions in the same time, I thought you meant separately.$$\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^1 \sqrt{(x-1)(y-1)(x-1+y)}dxdy\overset{x-1=a}=\int_0^1 \int_{-y}^0 \sqrt{a(y-1)(a+y)}dady$$
And now I had in mind the substitution $-a=xy$ (which isolates $a$ and $y$ from $a+y$), to get:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sqrt{x(1-x)} y^2\sqrt{1-y} dxdy$$

Comment: @Dan: It seems you answered [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877850), in which the OP posted their own answer but didn't manage to evaluate the integral analytically. Perhaps you want to post an answer or comment there?

Comment: @joriki I've left a comment there linking to this question.

Comment: @Dan: I now also came across [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103186). The last comment under that question links to [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24340565?seq=1) (*Expected Areas of Randomly Generated Triangles of Fixed Perimeter* by Douglass, Fitzgerald and Mihalik ($2002$), $\Pi$ME Journal, Vol. $11$, No. $7$, pp. $365$–$371$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue with
$$I= \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1-b}^0\sqrt{ab(a+b+1)}dadb
$$
along with the variable changes $a={u+v}$ and $b={u-v}$, to decouple the double integral

\begin{align}
I= \int_{-\frac1{2}}^0\int^{-u}_u
2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)(2u+1)}dv du
\end{align}
Then, utilize $\int_{-u}^u \sqrt{u^2–v^2}dv=\frac\pi2 u^2$ to obtain

$$I=\pi  \int_{-\frac1{2}}^0 {u^2}
\sqrt{2u+1}\ du=\frac{2\pi}{105}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Inner integral does not yield $0-0$.  In fact, it is
the difference of these two:
$$
{\frac {{y}^{2}\arcsin(1)}{16}\sqrt {1-y}}
\\ \text{and} \\
{\frac {{y}^{2}\arcsin(-1)}{16}\sqrt {1-y}}
$$
They are not the same.

---

Added.

The inner integral.
In your attempt, you wrote $\sqrt{y-1}$, square-root of a negative number.  Do you really want to do that?  You wrote $\sinh^{-1}(i)$ which is $i \sin^{-1}(1)=i\pi/2$.

Using only **real** nubers, the inner integral is
$$
{\frac {{y}^{2}\pi}{8}\sqrt {1-y}} .
$$

Are you really saying you don't know how to do
$$
\frac {\pi}{8}\int_0^1 {y}^{2}\sqrt {1-y}\;dy
$$

Comment: Thanks, I found the mistake I was making, and have editted. But I still don't know how to finish the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> > Use the following result which is very interested:
> > $$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi(b-a)^2}{8}.\tag 1$$
> > For detail we can refer [Area of semi-disk](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1107557p5025517).

Let $$D=\{(x,y)\mid0\leq y\leq1,1-y\leq x\leq1\},$$
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(1-x)(1-y)(x+y-1)},\quad (x,y)\in D,$$
then
$$I=\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(x-1)(y-1)(x+y-1)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
=\iint_{D}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$
By $(1)$, we get
$$\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(1-x)[x-(1-y)]}\ \mathrm dx=\frac{\pi y^2}{8},$$
so
$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-y}\cdot\frac{\pi y^2}{8}\mathrm dy
=\frac{2\pi}{105}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Self-answering.

With help from [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B%5C%2840%29x-1%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29y-1%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29x%2By-1%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D) for the inner anti-derivative, and using $\sinh^{-1}A=\log(A+\sqrt{A^2+1})$, we have:

$\begin{align}
\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(x-1)(y-1)(x+y-1)}\mathrm dx&=\left[-\frac14y^2\sqrt{y-1}\ln\left({\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{y}}+\sqrt{\frac{x+y-1}{y}}}\right)\right]_{1-y}^1\\
&=-\frac14y^2\sqrt{y-1}\ln{i}\\
&=-\frac{\pi i}{8}y^2\sqrt{y-1}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}y^2\sqrt{1-y}
\end{align}$

Then the integral in the OP is

$$\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1y^2\sqrt{1-y}\mathrm dy=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[-\frac{2}{105}(1-y)^{3/2}(15y^2+12y+8)\right]_0^1=\frac{2\pi}{105}$$

Answer (score 1):

At the begining, if we write the inner integral as
$$\sqrt{1-y}\int_{1-y}^1\sqrt{(1-x)(y+x-1)}dx$$
then by $1-x=u$
$$\sqrt{1-y}\int_{0}^{y}\sqrt{yu-u^2}du$$
and by $\frac y2-u=\frac y2\sin v$, we have
$$\frac14y^2\sqrt{1-y}\int_{\frac{-\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi} 2}\cos^2vdv=\frac\pi 8 y ^2\sqrt{1-y}$$
Trigonometric way we know, works in real world. I mean no i.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^1 \int_{1-y}^1 \sqrt{(1-x)(1-y)(x+y-1)} d x d y \\
& =\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y} \int_{1-y}^1 \sqrt{(1-x)(x+y-1)} d x d y \\
& =\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y} \cdot\frac{y^2}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^2 2 \theta d \theta,\quad \textrm{via the substitution } y\sin \theta=1-x\\&= \frac{\pi}{8} \int_0^1 y^2 \sqrt{1-y}\ d y\\& =\frac{2 \pi}{105} \quad (\textrm{ via integration by parts twice })
\end{aligned}
$$